# HpCISSs2.sys could not be found

Tags: windows, hard-drive

I tried to run **Mini Windows XP** on my machine but it says **"HpCISSs2.sys could not be found"**, but when I tried to load it in my other machine, **Mini Windows XP** was loaded successfully! Im using **Hirens Boot CD**. Any idea on how to fix this one?

**GOAL:** My goal was to rescue my files from my dead OS.

Answer (score 0):

You should go to BIOS (press F9 when reboot), then disable Virtual Install Disk in Advanced Options. Hope this helpful!

Tom.